# Android Getting Object ID from List View?

Tags: android, listview

I basically have 3 different objects in my list view:

`TextView1
TextView2
TextView3`

I want to get the object ID from the list view that's created dynamically. Ex: How do I set TextView2 with a background image from a list view in position 1?

I've tried using

`lv.getItemAtPosition(1);`

This will return the whole row and I'm just looking for the object ID `TextView2` inside `lv.getItemAtPosition(1)`? Once I get the `objectI`D from a certain position in list view, I can than change the `TextView`2 background.

Sorry, if I didn't explain clear enough. Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If you write about row, I assume something like that can work for you:

```
TableRow tableRow = lv.getItemAtPosition(1);
for (int i = 0; i < tableRow.getChildCount(); i++) {
  View child = tableRow.getChildAt(i);
  if ( child instanceof TextView ) {
TextView textView = (TextView) child;
    textView.DO_SOMETHIG__WITH_TEXT_VIEV();
textView.requestLayout();
}
}
tableRow.requestLayout();
```

Of course if you have some other row than tableRow, you can try to change it to that type.

Comment: TableRow tableRow = lv.getItemAtPosition(1); This line gives me....
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to TableRow

Comment: It is just an example, change tableRow to the type you get from lv.getItemAtPosition()